# Change the original branch for a feature branch

Tags: git, version-control, branching-and-merging

So I have a feature branch `new-feature` that I branched from `master`.

Now, I have to keep the same changes that I did in this branch, but change the underlying master to a different branch `master-2`, so that my pull requests now goto `master-2`.

How can I do this in git?

(I could stash the commits from `new-feature` and apply it as a patch to a new branch from `master-2`, but that would not change my current pull requests to `master` branch. I effectively want to migrate to a new base-branch.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least 2 options.

If `master` is an ancestor of `master-2`, then you could rebase:

```
git rebase master-2
```

Or else, you could create a new branch and cherry-pick the range of revisions:

```
git checkout -b new-feature-2
git cherry-pick master..new-feature
```

Comment: Yes, the `master-2` split from `master` a while ago. But it can be rebased over `master` again. So I think I could rebase on `master-2`. Thanks.

Comment: And if you need more complicated targeting, see rebase's `--onto` option.